# Maven parent and aggregator pom at the same time

Tags: java, maven

I have project `A` which depends on project `B` which depends on project `C`
i need when build project `A` ,project `B` will automatically build which will automatically build project `C`

in project `A` i created a parent pom which contains module for project `B`

```
<modules>
    <module>../B</module>
</modules>
```

in project `B` another parent pom with module for project `C`

```
<modules>
    <module>../C</module>
</modules>
```

and finally in project `A` pom file i added the parent element of Project `A`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>groupId.A</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId.A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>parent-pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

when build project `A` it always fails because it cannot see dependency `B`

what i need is to automat the build sequence project after project without creating aggregate project. is that possible?

```
root
|-- Project A
|   |-- parent-pom.xml
|   |-- pom.xml
|
|-- Project B
|   |-- parent-pom.xml
|   |-- pom.xml
|
|-- Project C
|   |-- pom.xml
|
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the directory structure of your projects...

Comment: @khmarbaise, done

Comment: Ah..please make text instead of images..furthemore are those projects related or unrelated ? Do you checkout them from a single source (svn or git repo) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, those projects are siblings at the same parent directory  and i don't use source control now .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make maven build of child module with parent module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689425/how-to-make-maven-build-of-child-module-with-parent-module)

Comment: First using VCS is a foundation of any development so I encourage you to learn a version control system. Furthermore make a parent `pom.xml` at the root location with modules `A`, `B`and `C` and the define the dependencies between the modules by simply dependencies...afterwards you can build from top via `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean verfiy`...no need for such `parent-pom.xml` files... Example like: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee