# How to configure maven based project?

Tags: maven

I have a Spring Boot 2 project, the pom of this project contains some dependencies and two of those dependiencies are my another projects (libs). Lets call it LP1 and LP2.

To make SpringBoot run possible, I always need to run "mvn clean install" in the folder of LP1 than run it again in LP2  and now finaly run it again on SpringBoot2 project. Otherwise I got an error cause maven cant find LP1 or LP2 or both.

It is possible to configure my projects another way so I can run "mvn clean install" just once? My Folder Structre looks like this

Root

-SpringBootProjectFolder

-LP1

-LP2

Comment: Is "root" really a folder one level higher than LP1, LP2? Can you draw somehow the folder structure ?

Comment: Hi, wirth root i mean my workspace all of my projects are inside this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a parent Pom for your project and add LP1 and LP2 as dependent modules. This way triggering the build for parent project will first build sub modules. For more details refer this [How to make maven build of child module with parent module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689425/how-to-make-maven-build-of-child-module-with-parent-module)